# By which way I can prove $\arctan\left(2^{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)<\frac{61}{125}$

Tags: inequality

By which way I can prove $$\arctan\left(2^{\sqrt{3}-\sqrt{7}}\right)<\frac{61}{125}$$

Comment: Could you give some context or thoughts on the problem so far?

Comment: I tried to prove it by taylor series but I countered problem with the square roots

Comment: Do you expect there to be a neat solution (without actually calculating very much)?

Comment: @JefLaga, I think so

Comment: This is [very close](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=61%2F125-arctan+%282%5E%28sqrt%283%29-sqrt%287%29%29), the difference is less than $10^{-7}$ so you will need very accurate approximations if you do it that way.

Comment: Damn! It didn't work! There was a minor error in my _intended_ solution.

Comment: @barto, I actually did but then I deleted it since it was flawed.

Comment: [Oh, boy ...](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/19188)

Comment: Try this in SageMath `RBF(arctan(2^(sqrt(3)-sqrt(7))))<61/125`. See document [here](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/rings_numerical/sage/rings/real_arb.html).